# Why are my charFormat styles only working on selections, and only those made in a specific direction?

Tags: python, qt, pyqt5, pyside2, qtextedit

I've been trying to be more explicit in my assignment of character formats for a text editor so that I can understand what I might be able to customize with my current skill range. While the basic copy-paste versions of my format methods worked pretty well, the version below keeps working and then not working in frustrating ways and need help figuring out what might be causing it.

The editor was originally intended to be a WYSIWYG editor styled via tags for documentation. Qt's confusing use of Html hasn't made that easy.

---

My basic flow is to extract a copy of the current format, check its current state, invert it, and reapply the format to the position or selection it was extracted from.

```py
# textEdit is a QTextEdit with a loaded document.

# This function is one of several related pairs called by a switchboard.
# It's intent is to invert the italic state of the current position/selection.

def toggle_italic_text(textEdit):
    # Get the cursor, and the format's state at its current selection/position.
    cursor = textEdit.textCursor()
    charFormat = cursor.charFormat()
    currentState = charFormat.fontItalic()

    # Invert the state within the format.
    print(currentState)
    charFormat.setFontItalic(not currentState)
    print(charFormat.fontItalic())

    # Reapply the format to the cursor's current selection/position.
    cursor.mergeCharFormat(charFormat)
```

When I first implemented it, this worked find. Now, it only works on selections, and even then it seems to identify the wrong state depending which direction I make a selection. After experimenting with it, it appears that if I make a selection to the right, it inverts correctly. If I make a selection to the left, it doesn't.

When trying to assign it to a position *without* a selection, the printed state changes from False to True, which is desired, yet the effect doesn't apply as I type. If I run it repeatedly in place, it continues to change from False to True, meaning the change is being lost.

The function is being called consistently and running through completely. The stored state of the charFormat copy does change.

**Why has this pattern stopped working? Am I using charFormats wrong? Why does the direction of selection change the results?**

As far as what changed on my end, I had been getting lost in my styling efforts after needing to apply styles through QFonts, QCharFormats, QPalette, and CSS stylesheets (and doc.defaultStylesheet) targeting both widgets and html tags. I desperately wanted my styles to be controlled through one approach, but couldn't figure out the hierarchy or find an approach that applied widely enough. In the end, I stripped out everything except for the stylesheet assigned to the window.

If there's no issue with the code itself, I'm really hoping for hints at what might be disrupting things. It took me awhile to get used to the idea that cursors and formats are copies meant to be changed and reapplied, while the document and its blocks are the real structure.

Comment: How should the "inversion" work? If you have a selection that contains both italic and not italic characters, should all of them be inverted? Or do you want to use the cursor position as a reference and apply the inverted style to the whole selection, no matter the current state?

Comment: If there's multiple italic states within the selection, the first toggle should align the entire selection to one state or the other. Subsequent toggles would invert the entire selection back and forth.I hadn't considered what rule exactly would determine that first behavior. I had assumed Qt's built-in functions were somehow handling it (that they don't always do so is why I'm intent on writing the full, explicit pattern).

Comment: They do, you just have to understand how to correctly use them. See my answer. For future reference, try to be more concise in your next. Questions that are too extensive and provide too many details (with many of them unnecessary) tend to be ignored.

Comment: Will do. I allowed too many questions to pile up on my end and now they're hard to separate cleanly.

Comment: Please, *DO NOT* edit your question (which was already too extensive) to include an answer or an explanation that refers to an existing answer. It makes the question more confusing, and doesn't really improve the context. If you have an *actual* answer, create it on your own. Otherwise, use comments.

Comment: Sorry. I was just being thorough and adding the sort of information I wish existed on the questions I rely on in my own searching. In particular, I'd described the error in my intuition rather than just the necessary syntax. I'd also extended the pattern to include an override and an adjusted use of the cursors and wasn't sure where that belonged.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The important thing that must be considered about [`QTextCursor.charFormat()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtextcursor.html#charFormat) is this:

> Returns the format of the *character* immediately **before** the cursor **position()**.

So, not only this doesn't work very well with selections that include multiple character formats, but you also have to consider the cursor position, which might change in a selection: it could be at the beginning (so it would return the format of the character *before* the selection), or at the end (returning the format of the *last* character in the selection).

If you want to invert the state based on the current cursor position (if at the beginning, use the first character, if at the end, use the last), then you can use the following:

```
    def toggle_italic_text(self):
        cursor = self.textEdit.textCursor()
        if not cursor.hasSelection():
            charFormat = cursor.charFormat()
            charFormat.setFontItalic(not charFormat.fontItalic())
            cursor.setCharFormat(charFormat)
            # in this case, the cursor has to be applied to the textEdit to ensure
            # that the following typed characters use the new format
            self.textEdit.setTextCursor(cursor)
            return

        start = cursor.selectionStart()
        end = cursor.selectionEnd()
        newCursor = QtGui.QTextCursor(self.textEdit.document())
        newCursor.setPosition(start)

        if cursor.position() == start:
            cursor.setPosition(start + 1)
        charFormat = cursor.charFormat()
        charFormat.setFontItalic(not charFormat.fontItalic())
        newCursor.setPosition(end, cursor.KeepAnchor)
        newCursor.mergeCharFormat(charFormat)
```

If you want to invert *all* states in the selection, you need to cycle through all characters.
While you could just change the char format for each character, that wouldn't be a very good thing for very large selections, so the solution is to apply the italic only when the char format actually changes from the previous state, *and* when at the end of the selection.

```
    def toggle_italic_text(self):
        # ...
        start = cursor.selectionStart()
        end = cursor.selectionEnd()
        newCursor = QtGui.QTextCursor(self.textEdit.document())
        newCursor.setPosition(start)

        cursor.setPosition(start)
        prevState = cursor.charFormat().fontItalic()
        while cursor.position() < end:
            cursor.movePosition(cursor.Right)
            charFormat = cursor.charFormat()
            if charFormat.fontItalic() != prevState or cursor.position() >= end:
                newPos = cursor.position()
                if cursor.position() < end:
                    newPos -= 1
                newCursor.setPosition(newPos, cursor.KeepAnchor)
                charFormat.setFontItalic(not prevState)
                newCursor.mergeCharFormat(charFormat)
                prevState = not prevState
                newCursor.setPosition(cursor.position() - 1)
```

Comment: Thanks, I think this is exactly the insight I need to solve things on my end (I'll update when I find time to mess with it). Qt provides access to formats and fonts through most of the different text classes, yet it's hard to know which ones have unique function, which ones simply call through to lower classes, and when/which default styles are used. The cursor exists in negative space between characters, so seeing how it samples, receives, and applies its own reference to a charFormat is helpful. Consciously noting which character is sampled and the consequences of that is great too.

Comment: Basically, all text related widgets in Qt use QTextDocument in some way, some explicitly (like QTextEdit subclasses) others privately (such as QLabel); understanding how it works (along with QTextCursor, QTextBlock and QTextFormat subclasses) is not certainly an easy task, but if you do some studying and experimenting you'll begin to get the gist of it. About the cursor, you could consider it as a form of slice notation.

Comment: Worked! I included an `overrideState=None` parameter which, when given a boolean allows the function to choose the outcome rather than toggling. I think it may also be the case that the initial position for newCursor should be the end position (which samples the last character) rather than the start position (which samples the first -1). That way the options are between the first and last characters, rather than first and first-1.

Comment: I'm not sure I've understood your last part. The start position of `newCursor` should always be the index of the first character, with the end position (when moving while keeping anchor) set on the position of `cursor.position() -1` (since `cursor` has advanced one more character right to check for format changes).

Comment: I was wrong. I was referring to the first example rather than the fully inverted version which I haven't explored yet, and because I used my `cursor`/`newCursor` pair slightly differently, I misread your flow. I left the existing selection on `cursor`, and used `newCursor` exclusively to sample the first or last character. You swapped those roles and had to rebuild the selection on `newCursor`. I'll update my finished code (with the added override) in my original post.